# Search result in Google

Tags: html

In the image below I have a search results from Google. I wonder what this type of detailed search result is called and how it's done? Thanks!

[image: Search result from Google]

Comment: I've always wondered the same thing. My guess (keyword) is that is has something to do with sitemaps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the internals of Google search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about **sitelinks**. Please have a look to: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

As stated in the article, it is not something you can force, Google decides whether your site is worth to have them or not.

Comment: OK! Your answer gave me the info I was looking for! Thanks!